# Error contains an invalid type, it should be an object, or a null docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am getting following error

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  app-1:
    container_name: app-1
    image: app/app:1.0.0
    networks:
      app_network:
        - ipv4_address: 192.28.0.2

  app-2:
    container_name: app-2
    image: app/app:1.0.0
    networks:
      app_network:
        - ipv4_address: 192.28.0.3

  app-3:
    container_name: app-3
    image: app/app:1.0.0
    networks:
      app_network:
        - ipv4_address: 192.28.0.4

networks:
  app_network:
    driver: default
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.28.0.0/16
          gateway: 192.28.0.1
```

Getting following error

```
docker-compose up -d
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because:
services.app-1.networks.app_network contains an invalid type, it should be an object, or a null
services.app-2.networks.app_network contains an invalid type, it should be an object, or a null
services.app-3.networks.app_network contains an invalid type, it should be an object, or a null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is on your app_network section, can you try with?

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  app-1:
    container_name: app-1
    image: app/app:1.0.0
    networks:
      app_network:
        ipv4_address: 192.28.0.2 #without -

  app-2:
    container_name: app-2
    image: app/app:1.0.0
    networks:
      app_network:
        ipv4_address: 192.28.0.3 #without -

  app-3:
    container_name: app-3
    image: app/app:1.0.0
    networks:
      app_network:
        ipv4_address: 192.28.0.4 #without -

networks:
  app_network:
    driver: default
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.28.0.0/16
          gateway: 192.28.0.1
```